# three.js shows faces of transparent objects

Tags: three.js

Okay, I guess that the title was a little broad, but if you visit http://businessbuilder.co.nf/, you'll see that the transparent water tiles show the faces in a darker shade where they meet.
I've tried multiple different approaches to fixing this problem and none of them work.
So, I thought I'd ask StackOverflow.

So, any ideas?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36948438/1461008).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by having the opacity set on all of the faces. That way when they are drawn, the semi-transparent ones "collide" to make a darker area.

Comment: Okay, I see... So I should set only the top face to the opacity, and have every other face completely transparent?

Comment: Solved. Thank you.

Comment: No, you want all faces to have the same opacity.

Comment: You are welcome @KrystalFox. Please remember to mark the accepted answer by clicking the tick under the answer's score :) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I have to wait a few more minutes before I can accept your answer.