# How can I eliminate the dark regions in my transparent material?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am showing a shoe model in the browser with three.js. I have a problem when I set the heel to a half-transparent material. I have used the orbitControls in the project and when I rotate to some angle the half-transparent material shows the dark spot and frag triangle ?

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

How can I change the material properties to set the material to a pure color? I have set the material props like this

```
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    specular: materialParams.material3d.specular,
    shininess: materialParams.material3d.shininess,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: materialParams.material3d.opacity,       
    map: that.textureLoader.load(this.sourceUrl + 
    materialParams.material3d.icon),
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    blending: THREE["NormalBlending"]

})
```

Comment: check this article [Here](https://aboosbox.wordpress.com/2017/04/17/three-js-for-absolute-beginners/) You may got solution !!

Comment: Please show a screenshot of that dark spot you were talking about.

Comment: thanks,I upload a wrong shotScreen...,now I upload it again in the start link

Comment: @feixiangsnail (1) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947704/rendering-a-transparent-shell. (2) But first, just try: `side: THREE.FrontSide`, and do not set the blending mode.

Comment: thank you very much ,I work it out in your way,it is the problem of the side,when I set side: THREE.FrontSide,it well done. Stack Overflow is really a good forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semi-transparent faces are rendered in the order they appear in buffer. This can lead to artifacts or "dark spots" in semi-transparent materials.

Since the geometry of your "heel" appears to be convex, an easy fix that may be satisfactory is to render only front faces:

```
mesh.material.side = THREE.FrontSide;
```

When the material is transparent and the geometry is more complicated, you may need to try other solutions. One alternate approach is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36948438/1461008);

three.js r.85

Comment: please can you help me with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693337/modify-three-js-pointerlock-controls-example-to-make-it-fly)?