# How can I tween opacity in Three.js without seeing inside a mesh?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to tween in the opacity of a complex mesh loaded from an obj file, however, when tweening the mesh's material you can see all the geometry inside the mesh overlapping each other in the scene. Is there a way to avoid this effect when tweening in Three.js?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947704/rendering-a-transparent-shell

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.