# transparent material rendering artifacts

Tags: three.js, transparency

I have a 3d surface which  I would like to make it transparent so the map under it is visible. 
The problem is that some face hidden are rendered not making the transparency constant (highlighted). Is possible to render the yellow/green of the right image transparent without these artefacts?

[image: image with overlapped faces in the back]

Comment: See if [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36948438/1461008) solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been able to fix it and post how I did it . Since the question was made already, should I delete this question?

Comment: Usually it would be marked as a duplicate. You can delete the question if you want.

Comment: @WestLangley can you add more context as to why this works?

Answer (score 1):

Folling @WestLangley comment I was able to fix the issue rendering twice:
once  `colorWrite = false` and then `colorWrite = true` . The simplest way I found is with a MultiMaterialObject.

```
let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(
    { color: 0xffffff88,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      opacity: 0.4,
      transparent: true,
      colorWrite : false,
      vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
      shininess: 60
    } )

let material_cw = material.clone()
material_cw.colorWrite = true

let mesh  = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( 
            geometry,[material,material_cw] )
```

[image: render artifact fixed]