# Threejs transparent materials union blending

Tags: three.js

I have two different objects with the same transparent material in threejs, and I want to blend them in a "non-additive" way like in the following picture. There are three boxes: one blue in the background and two transparent yellow boxes in the foreground. The left image is how it currently is, and the right image is what I want. Is there a kind of material / possibly shader that can achieve this effect?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947704/rendering-a-transparent-shell

Comment: Thanks! The colorWrite / renderOrder trick works for most of my cases with one caveat: if there are a lot transparent boxes, they still go darker (4 identical boxes at the same position).

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.