# How to avoid transparency overlap using threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, mapbox-gl

I am using threejs to build a map application, and I need to make all building models translucent, but in this case, the transparent buildings will overlap, resulting in a confusing display effect, as shown in the following figure

[Overlapping renderings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HOld.png)

The effect I hope to achieve is similar to the example on mapboxgl, the nearby buildings can directly block the buildings behind, which is much more refreshing

[Expected renderings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXJZ8.png)

How can this be done?

```
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xcccccc );
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xcccccc, 0.002 );
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x4186D1 );
            // scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x4186D1, 0.002 );
            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x4186D1, 800, 1800 );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.set( 400, 200, 0 );

            // controls

            controls = new MapControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

            controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // call this only in static scenes (i.e., if there is no animation loop)

            controls.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
            controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

            controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

            controls.minDistance = 100;
            controls.maxDistance = 500;

            controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

            // world

            const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            geometry.translate( 0, 0.5, 0 );
            const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, transparent: true, opacity: 0.7, flatShading: true } );

            for ( let i = 0; i < 500; i ++ ) {

                const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                mesh.position.x = Math.random() * 1600 - 800;
                mesh.position.y = 0;
                mesh.position.z = Math.random() * 1600 - 800;
                mesh.scale.x = 20;
                mesh.scale.y = Math.random() * 80 + 10;
                mesh.scale.z = 20;
                mesh.updateMatrix();
                mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                scene.add( mesh );

            }

            // lights

            const dirLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            dirLight1.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( dirLight1 );

            const dirLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
            dirLight2.position.set( - 1, - 1, - 1 );
            scene.add( dirLight2 );

            const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
            scene.add( ambientLight );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );


            const gui = new GUI();
            gui.add( controls, 'screenSpacePanning' );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36947704/1461008

Comment: yes, it's great. thanks WestLangley