# ThreeJs Merged Shape Geometries remove overlapping transparency while still being transparent for other objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have multiple 2D [shape](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/core/Shape) [geometries](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ShapeGeometry) merged together into one single buffer geometry with [mergeBufferGeometries](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries). This new geometry is then used together with a material to create a mesh (e.g. The green colored mesh below). This mesh is transparent, so you can see other objects (e.g. the blue one) through that mesh.

```js
   // geoemetrys is an array of ShapeGeometry
   const mergedGeometries = mergeBufferGeometries(geoemetrys);
   const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
         color: new THREE.Color("red"),
         opacity: 0.1,
         transparent: true,
         side: THREE.FrontSide,
   });
   const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeometries, material);
```

Now the problem is that the merged geometries overlap in opacity, causing darker areas where different paths join. I would like the shape geometry to have a consistent opacity althrought, while still being transparent for other objects (like the blue one).

[image]

I've already tried using `material.colorWrite = false` described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947704/rendering-a-transparent-shell/36948438#36948438) which works fine with 3D objects, but because all of individual shape geometries have the same `z`-value, that approach didn't work.
I've also tried using CSG and combining the different individual geometries into one by using union boolean operations, but that approach is way too laggy because I need to create many shapes.
I've now come across blending, and that approach seems to work quite well:

```js
blending: THREE.CustomBlending,
blendEquation: THREE.AddEquation,
blendSrc: THREE.SrcAlphaFactor,
blendSrcAlpha: THREE.OneFactor,
blendDst: THREE.ZeroFactor,
depthFunc: THREE.LessEqualDepth,
depthWrite: true,
```

with these properties added to the material parameters and the alpha property of the renderer set to `true`. Now this approach ([found here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/18791)) works well in respect that the shape has a constant transparency, but now the shape isn't transparent for other shapes anymore, and the transparency doesn't overlap with other shapes anymore:

[image]

I am not experience with blending and depth at all, so I don't really now hot to adjust these to achieve what I want (and don't know if it even is possible).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you please add your code so far?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/36948438/1461008.

Comment: You have to use something an extrude from three shape.

Comment: @WestLangley tbh, I tried it but I don't know how to implement this properly, what is meant by rendering it a second time? Just adding a second element or adding it to a new scene ? Either way it didn't work ...

Comment: @purple Two instances of the same mesh are added to the scene. The first instance is rendered with `material.colorWrite = false`.  See the fiddle posted in the _comments_ of the above link.

Comment: @WestLangley this only works tho if the objects have a different z value. The merged geometries all have the same z value, so it's basically 2D.

Comment: It would be helpful to make that clear in your question.

Comment: @purple You could try making the full triangle `Shape` before converting it into a `Geometry`. If you could create a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on jsfiddle.net or codepen.io, I might be able to see if there's a solution to your specific implementation.

Comment: @Marquizzo like already said the Geometry is made up by multiple individual shape geometries. This shape doesnt have to be a triangle though. Combining the shapes with CSG or anything else is not a possibility because of performance.

Comment: @purple If you could create [a minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on https://jsfiddle.net or https://codepen.io, I might be able to see if there's a solution to your specific implementation.